# change button background in an function on android sdk 15 and below

Tags: java, android

on SDK 16 and above I can change button background by

```
messagesButton.setBackground(swapDrawable);
```

but this function does not work on sdk 15 and below. Is there a different way to change button background programmatically ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe if you try button and look through the methods you would find it.

```
button.setBackgroundDrawable()
```

there is also

```
button.setBackgroundResource()
```

To use with R ids.